# Quasar: Router push de login no carga router-view del mainlayout

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-router, quasar, routerlink

Buen día. Tengo el siguiente formulario de mi archivo "pages/Login.vue" que al momento de verificar que los datos son correctos "debería" redireccionarme al index en mi Mainlayout.
Aquí el formulario:

```
<template>
<div>
    <q-form @submit="btnlogin">
     <q-input v-model="user" type="text" label="Usuario" />
     <q-input v-model="pass" type="password" label="Contraseña" />
    <q-btn color="primary" label="Ingresar" type="submit"/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useQuasar } from 'quasar'
import router from 'src/router/index'
export default {
  setup () {
      const $q = useQuasar()

      const user = ref(null)
      const pass = ref(null)
      const btnlogin = async () => {
          axios.post("http://localhost:3050/loginQuest",{
            uss : user.value,
            pww : pass.value
          })
          .then(resp=>{
            if(resp.data=="ERROR"){
              $q.notify({
                type:'negative',
                message:'Datos incorrectos!'
              })
            } 
            else{
              router().push({ path: '/' })
            } 
          })
      }
    return {
        user, pass, btnlogin
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Cuando la verificación es correcta la barra de dirección cambia a http://localhost:8080 pero el contenido no cambia y el formulario de Login.vue sigue mostrándose en pantalla.

Este es mi router/routes.js:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') },
      { path: '/form', component: () => import('pages/Form.vue') },
      { path: '/user', component: () => import('pages/Usuarios.vue') },
      { path: '/prueba', component: () => import('pages/Prueba.vue') },
      { path: '/facturas', component: () => import('pages/Facturas.vue') },
    ],
  },
  { path: '/login', component:()=> import('pages/Login.vue')},
  { path: '/:catchAll(.*)*', component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')}
]

export default routes
```

Cambié la configuración de quasar.conf.js en el apartado de "vueRouterMode" de hash a history.
Espero puedan ayudarme, que ando estancado en ello.
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: En tus rutas, cambia `{ path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') }` por esto `{ path: '/', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') }`. Observa la barra `/` en el **path**

Comment: Buen día. Acabo de hacer lo mencionado, pero no me resultó. Anduve probando con la funcion "router().go({path:'/'})" pero tampoco me funcionó. Gracias por tu comentario :)

Comment: Tal vez deberías probar nombrando la ruta, ejemplo `{ path: '', name: 'Index', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') }` y haces el `push()` con referencia a ese nombre: `router().push({ name: 'Index' })`

Comment: Aunque pensándolo bien, deberías revisar la consola, creo que te va a mandar un error allí. ¿Haciendo un `$router.push()` hacia otra ruta funciona bien?

Comment: Lo conseguí estimado! No lo debí trabajar en el "setup()", sino que trasladé todo lo que contenía este y creé un método, y las referencias las volqué return del "data():" en ese contexto la función "this.$router.push({ path: '/' })" si funciona correctamente y el path trabaja. Quizá en el setup la forma de trabajar con el Router sea distinta, buscaré mas información, pero de momento es la solución que encontré. Tomé muy en cuenta tu segundo comentario donde mencionaste el "$router.push()" y con eso se me prendió el foco! muchas gracias y saludos coordiales!

Comment: Perfecto amigo, buenisimo..!!

Comment: como solucionaste el error disculpa, tengo el mismo problema